# Complex Encryption and Decryption of String using UTF8 vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can any one let me know that how to Encrption and Decryption of String using UTF8 vb.net.

Comment: By writing code. Where's yours?

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function EncryptString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
        Dim memStream As MemoryStream = Nothing
        Try
            Dim key As Byte() = {}
            Dim IV As Byte() = {12, 21, 43, 17, 57, 35, 67, 27}
            Dim encryptKey As String = "aXb2uy4z"
            key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey)
            Dim byteInput As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString)
            Dim provider As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
            memStream = New MemoryStream
            Dim transform As ICryptoTransform = provider.CreateEncryptor(key, IV)
            Dim cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(memStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cryptoStream.Write(byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length)

            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray())
    End Function


Public Function DecryptString(ByVal inputString As String) As String

                Return Convert.DecryptString(inputString) 
End Function
```

Comment: I think, This is what i require.. Thanks. Vivek

Comment: A little attribution would be nice :) http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1354.html

Comment: I have been wondering for quite a while how Vivek was managing proper answers from time to time. I got my answer : plagiarism. Even worse than I thought...

Comment: do you have any problem in this.?

Comment: Of course I do, but as I have told you before, if you don't take the time to read the help section, you'll keep getting surprised by the rules of this site : http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @2Dee, Why you have downvoted my answer? Dont follow me, You are Such a irritating personality i have ever seen in my life. You are just like your photo.

Comment: I explained the reason above, and I also said that if you only bothered to read the help section and stopped trying to cheat your way to high rep, you'd be less frustrated. If reading 1 line is too much for you, there's nothing I can do. But plagiarism is not acceptable, and since you chose to ignore requests for attribution of the content you posted as yours, I downvote it, and I would do it again if I could. Personal attacks will not change anything to this, but it certainly drew my attention to you, so make sure you get your next question/answer right, because I will be there to read it...